# Cannot login as super administrator

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

Right now I am in the process of updating my Joomla 1.5.15 site, so I am trying to follow this.

http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_I_upgrade ... _to_3.x%3F

I found out that I had to first upgrade to site to 1.5.26 before doing 2.5x or 3.0x. So I am trying to backup the site using Akeeba Backup.I download it. But the problem is that when I go on my site to install the extension, I cannot find the extension manager.

However, the real problem is that I cannot login as the super administrator because my account is in "administrator" status. I don't have anything else. I am not sure what to do now because I am unable to find the right account name and details so I can use the extension manager.

Comment: Go to your data base and add yourself to the super admin user group.

Comment: I downloaded myPhpAdmin but I am unsure how to access my specific website with it

Comment: You should have it or something like it as part of your xampp or whatever you are using, you should not need to install unless you are building your own stack.

Comment: I do not have a xampp. I am not sure what to do...

Comment: Are you working locally or on a server somewhere? Most hosts supply phpmyadmin via some kind of control panel.

Comment: I use GoDaddy to host the website

Comment: Ask them what you should use to look at your database.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your user type,from your database go to `yourprefix_users` table and change the 
user type for your account,[this tutorial](http://docs.joomla.org/J1.5:How_do_you_recover_or_reset_your_admin_password%3F) might be helpful because it's refers to users tables in the database,I personally prefer to use PHPMyAdmin for this purpose.

Comment: I'm following that right now. I am not sure how to open my website in PHPmyadmin

Comment: you can't open your website from PHPMyAdmin,You can open your Database From PHPMyAdmin,if you have access to your web host's Control Panel,that would be easy,if your Control Panel is cPanel here is a tutorial for you,it's very Easy,https://manage.grabweb.in/knowledgebase/18/How-can-I-access-phpMyAdmin-from-cPanel.html

Comment: And from there I will be able to add an account for super administrator?

Comment: No do not add an account. Modify your exisitng account.

Answer (score 0):

You can download ad put on your server adminer, an one-file mysql database interface for managing your tables. It consists of a single php file that you can call from browser. It'll ask you to insert mysql credentials: you can find them in configuration.php file in joomla's root. Then you can make you existing user a super user.